# PrimeFaces area chart overlapping xaxis labels

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I am using PrimeFaces 5.1 and have a simple area chart which plots counts of three series over time.  What I am finding is that given the below example the times overlap and no lines are drawn.  I am not seeing any errors within the console.

From my bean:

```
private LineChartModel egmModel;

public void init() {
    egmModel = new LineChartModel();

    LineChartSeries g2scLCS = new LineChartSeries();
    g2scLCS.setFill(true);
    g2scLCS.setLabel(ComponentType.G2SSSC.getShortName());
    g2scLCS.set("12:50", 0);
    g2scLCS.set("12:51", 10);
    g2scLCS.set("12:51", 20);

    LineChartSeries vlcsscLCS = new LineChartSeries();
    vlcsscLCS.setFill(true);
    vlcsscLCS.setLabel(ComponentType.VLCSSC.getShortName());
    vlcsscLCS.set("12:50", 10);
    vlcsscLCS.set("12:51", 20);
    vlcsscLCS.set("12:51", 30);

    LineChartSeries totalLCS = new LineChartSeries();
    totalLCS.setFill(true);
    totalLCS.setLabel("Configured");
    totalLCS.set("12:50", 20);
    totalLCS.set("12:51", 30);
    totalLCS.set("12:51", 50);

    egmModel.addSeries(g2scLCS);
    egmModel.addSeries(vlcsscLCS);
    egmModel.addSeries(totalLCS);
    egmModel.setTitle("EGM's");
    egmModel.setLegendPosition("e");
    egmModel.setStacked(true);
    egmModel.getAxis(AxisType.X).setLabel("Time");
    egmModel.getAxis(AxisType.Y).setLabel("Count");
    egmModel.getAxis(AxisType.Y).setMin(0);
}

public LineChartModel getEgmModel() {
    return egmModel;
}
```

And the xhtml:

```
<p:chart id="egmChart" type="line" model="#{dxAgentBean.egmModel}" />
```

Does somebody have some idea what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I wasnt defining the X axis as being a Date axis.

```
    DateAxis minuteAxis = new DateAxis();       
    minuteAxis.setTickFormat("%R");
    minuteAxis.setMin("00:00");
    minuteAxis.setMax("23:59");
    minuteAxis.setTickInterval("7200");
    minuteAxis.setTickAngle(-1);
    minuteAxis.setLabel("Time");
```